# How to set fill out an array using memset

Tags: c

I have a Player struct that contains a GameBoard, which is a 2d array of chars.

When I use memset it does not set the array

I have tried using the address of the board (&, *) and without those symbols

I can get it to work if I use a pointer to the Player variable in 'initializeBoard' but the assignment says not to use a pointer

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

const int ROWS = 10;
const int COLS = 10;

const char *PLAYERONE = "Player 1";
const char *PLAYERTWO = "Player 2";
const char WATER = '~';
const int NUM_SHIPS = 5;

typedef struct gameBoard {
    char board[ROWS][COLS];
} GameBoard;

typedef struct human {
    char name[20];
    GameBoard gameBoard;
} Player;

// function prototypes

void displayGameBoard(Player player);
void initializeBoard(Player player);
void initializePlayer(Player *player, const char *name);






// main function
int main() {
    Player playerOne;
    Player playerTwo;
    // call function welcomeScreen

    initializePlayer(&playerOne, PLAYERONE);
    // end program
    return 0;
}

void displayGameBoard(Player player) {
    int row;
    int col;
    printf("%s's Game Board\n", player.name);
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("|   | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |\n");
    printf("---------------------------------------------\n");
    for (row = 0; row < ROWS; row++) {
        printf("| %d |", row);
        for (col = 0; col < COLS; col++) {
            printf(" %c |", player.gameBoard.board[row][col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("---------------------------------------------");
}

void initializeBoard(Player player) {
    memset(*player.gameBoard.board, WATER, sizeof(player.gameBoard.board));
}

void initializePlayer(Player *player, const char *name) {
    char playerName[20];
    GameBoard playerBoard;
    strcpy(player->name, playerName);
    player->gameBoard = playerBoard;
    initializeBoard(*player);
    displayGameBoard(*player);
}
```

I expect the result to be filled with '~' but it either corrupts the whole terminal or prints blanks

Comment: its better to provide small piece of code which is applicable only for your problem. Its time consuming to look through it

Comment: If you _know_ the problem is the memset call, is there a good reason to post quite that much code?

Comment: I cut down the amount of code

Comment: Don't copy the struct by value. You got it right in `initializePlayer` but wrong in `initializeBoard`. Voting to close this as simple typo.

Comment: When you call `strcpy(player->name, playerName);`, `playerName` hasn't been initialized -> undefined behaviour. Fix that first. Did you mean `strcpy(player->name, name);`?

Comment: @Lundin I do not think, that this can be classified as a "typo". The OP didn't know that he passes by value  this way (and probably that this is even possible with structs)

Comment: Also in `player->gameBoard = playerBoard;`, `playerBoard ` has never been initialized, you basically copy garbage.

Comment: @Ctx Since he got it right in one case I assume they already know of this and it was just a typo or hasty copy/paste issue.

Comment: @Lundin How can this be, you have to change the code at _several_ places to change it; removing the * alone doesn't suffice

Comment: It is a hasty delete issue, I do it elsewhere. I have the solution already. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
void initializeBoard(Player player) {
    memset(*player.gameBoard.board, WATER, sizeof(player.gameBoard.board));
}
```

You are passing the `Player` object by copy rather than reference.  The object you are setting, is not the object you intend to set, and is in any event temporary.  Passing large structures on the stack is also inefficient (you may want to reconsider the signature of `displayGameBoard()` too in that case).  Also the member `board` does not need to be dereferenced.

```
void initializeBoard(Player* player);

...

void initializeBoard(Player* player) 
{
    memset( player->gameBoard.board, WATER, sizeof(player->gameBoard.board));
}
```

Then call it in `initializePlayer()` thus:

```
initializeBoard(player);
```

Comment: @Trickzter That doesn't matter, he obviously started writing it before I posted it. I also absolutely dislike being in a hurry just to be the first to post (+1).

Comment: @Trickzter : What is your point? Check out the post timing. The answer was not posted when I started writing this - I cannot help it if there is one right answer and two people were concurrently answering it!  Besides, two people explaining the same thing may give different views or add clarity.

Comment: @Clifford I get that but for the sake of clearity and simplicity I think the redundancy is not necessary. You both clearified the same situation in the same way. Just wanted to keep this topic clear! I know that things like this happen easily and are common :)

Comment: @Trickzter : I am not about to delete the post because it was duplicated by a race condition.  Your SO rep does not indicate that you are qualified to be the arbiter of such things.  The way to raise the profile of an answer you like is to vote for it.  This duplication is harmless, and it seems now preferred by the OP in any case.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that you pass your Player-structure *by value* here:

```
initializeBoard(*player);
```

so you essentially are working on a *copy*. Pass a pointer and work on the original structure like this:

```
initializeBoard(player);
```

and change the initializeBoard-function to that:

```
void initializeBoard(Player *player) {
   memset(player->gameBoard.board, WATER, sizeof(player->gameBoard.board)); 
}
```

then it should work as expected. You should change the `displayBoard()` function, too, because there is no reason to pass by value and it is much more computation effort (copy the whole structure)